# why the local reparameterization trick only works only for fully connected networks?

Tags: bayesian, tensorflow

i was reading this article on [towarddatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-segmentation-with-uncertainty-via-3d-bayesian-convolutional-neural-networks-6b1c7277b078) and at a certain point the author says

"An important difference is that local reparametrization works only for fully connected networks, while Flipout can be used effectively in fully-connected, convolutional, and recurrent networks."

but i do not understand why the local reparameterization should be limited to fully connected networks.
Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this limitation? thanks

Comment: I see some loc reparam applied to CNN also https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417421013191 but are being published a year after that paper

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia can you explain me better the previous comment? i do not have a computer science background  and i did not understand the kernel part. what i know is that the local reparameterization trick  write the weight w as w= u + e*sigma where e is a random variable centered around 0 with variance equal to 1 and this is done for every weight. what's the problem with doing it for other architectures?

Comment: I've deleted that comment, however, what I was talking to si the "weight sharing in CNN", which is equivalent to "moving a filter along the channels of the incoming images, which are made of a kernel per channel"... the problem is not that "is not doable", but that the result might not be what you expect, of it might not have the properties of a bayesian NN